# Can I get additional information about the error from SAXParseException and XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, validation, xsd, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am using the default javax.API.validator for validating an XML file against an XSD i.e SAXParser

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(schemaPath));
            StreamSource XML = new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath));
            XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(XML);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.setErrorHandler(new BasicErrorHandler(reader));
            validator.validate(new StAXSource(reader));
```

Here is the ErrorHandler:

```
public class BasicErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private XMLStreamReader reader;

    public BasicErrorHandler(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        warning(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        warning(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(reader.getLocalName());
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
```

I can get the node that is invalid by calling reader.getLocalName()
but I tried all the methods on the reader but haven't been able to get to the value that causes this exception. For e.g id I have a tag as

```
<startDate>asdfasdf</startDate>
```

which is a date field according to the schema (XSD) 
From the code above I can the node i.e I can find out that startDate is the invalid field. But what is value that is invalid I am not able to deduce that.

Has anyone worked or faced similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it gives a full error message including the value that's invalid.

The `error` method of your `BasicErrorHandler` is called twice and holds a `SAXParseException` with following messages:

> cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'asdfasdf' is not a valid value for 'date'.

and

> cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'asdfasdf' of element 'startDate' is not valid.

It's not possible to get the invalid value as `String`. Because the `reader`'s position is beyond the text element (event type is `XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT`) when the error is triggered and SAX parses forward only.

Comment: But this is not the best way to get the error I assume. Because they are present in vague strings. They might be different tomorrow. But reader.getLocalName() returns precisely the fieldName and I would like something similar to that for field Value